# uninitialized constant during rake assets:precompile for lib class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Rails 3.2.2

When running rake assets:precompile I get the following error:

```
uninitialized constant Redirect
```

Redirect is a custom middleware class that redirects naked domain requests from mydomain.com to www.mydomain.com.

I load the middleware in production.rb using:

```
config.middleware.use Redirect
```

The redirect.rb is located at lib/middleware/redirect.rb.  I load the path in application.rb using:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib/middleware)
```

It works fine when you run the application, and other rake tasks run fine. But running rake assets:precompile appears to not load the lib properly.  I first noticed the issue running on Heroku, but I've been able to reproduce locally no problem.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: So, this is just a workaround hack, but i decided to just catch the exception in production.rb, which works both for the app, and for the assets:precompile task. I'd still like to figure out what the actual problem is though.

Answer (score 3):

You probably have `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false` set somewhere.

I experienced this error after setting that configuration for something related to Heroku.  To fix, i just `require "#{Rails.root}/lib/my_middleware.rb"` right above the line where I configure the app to use the middleware.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error for loading a class from /lib and assigning it to a `::GLOBAL` variable.

This was because I had forgotten to place it inside an `after_initialize` block, which is how I had done it in development.

```
config.after_initialize do
  ::GLOBAL = MyLib::MyClass.new
end
```

Hope this helps somebody!